# Is it possible to extract code into delegate?

Tags: c#, function, lambda, delegates, func

**Update:**
The issue I had is model validation, but I found FluentValidation already taking care of this when the model passed to Action, so my question is not completely correct and probably misleading. I will close it (if find how to do it).

I have the following code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateAccountViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            **await Mediator.Send(_mapper.Map<CreateAccountCommand>(model));
            return RedirectToAction("Index");**
        }
        catch (ValidationException vldEx)
        {
            foreach (var vldError in vldEx.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(vldError.PropertyName, vldError.ErrorMessage);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

The text inside the try is different for different actions of a controller, but everything else is the same. Is it possible to extract common code into function in the base class? 
I tried using Func, but can't' figure out the right way to do it. 
I am looking for something like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateAccountViewModel model)
    {
        FunctionWithCommonCode(x =>
        {
            await Mediator.Send(_mapper.Map<CreateAccountCommand>(model));
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for delegates or anything complicated just creates a base method that you call from each action and pass in the string you need, for example:

```
private async Task<IActionResult> CreateBase(CreateAccountViewModel model, string action)
{
    try
    {
        await Mediator.Send(_mapper.Map<CreateAccountCommand>(model));
        return RedirectToAction(action);
    }
    catch (ValidationException vldEx)
    {
        foreach (var vldError in vldEx.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(vldError.PropertyName, vldError.ErrorMessage);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And an action method would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateAccountViewModel model)
{
    return await CreateBase(model, "Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get this to compile - there are way too many dependencies on code that you did not provide.  If you can provide Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with enough stubbed out classes to get your example code to compile (without dependencies on code you don't provide), then I'll update my answer.

But, if I'm understanding your question, what you need to do is create a method that does everything except your `**star-ed**` code, and pass the star-ed code in as a parameter with the appropriate delegate type.  Sorry, but because I couldn't get things to compile, I'm not sure I have the asyncs and awaits in exactly the right place.  But, this should give you a head start.

So, you start with a worker function that provides all the boiler-plate:

```
private async Task<IActionResult> WebWorker<TModel> (TModel model, Func<TModel, Task<IActionResult>> workToDo) {
    try {
        return await workToDo(TModel model);
    } catch (ValidationException vldEx) {
        foreach (var vldError in vldEx.Errors) {
            ModelState.AddModelError(vldError.PropertyName, vldError.ErrorMessage);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

That function takes in your mode and a delegate of the appropriate `Func<>` type.

Then you call it something like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateAccountViewModel model) {
     return await WebWorker<CreateAccountViewModel>(model,
          m => {
             Mediator.Send(_mapper.Map<CreateAccountCommand>(m));
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         });
 }
```

Note that the second parameter to the `WebWorker` function is a Lambda whose signature matches that of the Func declared as the second parameter to that function.